# NextJS Firebase cloud functions verification error, app: missing

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to call a onCall firebase cloudfunction from my nextJS application. My cloudfunction looks like this:

```
const callCreate = onCall(
  {
    enforceAppCheck: true,
    consumeAppCheckToken: true,
    region: [constants.regions.default.functions, constants.regions.us.functions],
    minInstances: constants.functions.onCall.User.callCreate.minInstances,
  }, async (request) => {
    const email: string = request.data.email;
    const userID = request.auth?.uid;

    if (!userID) {
      throw new HttpsError("unauthenticated", "The function must be " +
        "called while authenticated.");
    }

    const database = getFirestoreInstance();
    
    await database.collection("User").doc(userID).collection("Private").doc("Account").set({
      Email: email,
    });
  }
);
```

When i call this cloudfunction using the following function, i will get a error logged by the firebase logs. My function to call the cloudfunctions looks the following:

```
export function callAddUser() {
  const data = {
    "gender": "female",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "BirthDay": "2023-08-31",
    "Password": "test"
  }

  const functions = getFunctions(app);
  functions.region = "europe-west4";

  const addUser = httpsCallable(functions, 'call-user-callCreate');
  addUser(data)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
}
```

The error will look like this:

```
function[europe-west4-call-user-callCreate]: Beginning execution of "europe-west4-call-user-callCreate"
function[europe-west4-call-user-callCreate]: Finished "europe-west4-call-user-callCreate" in 3.6632ms
function[europe-west4-call-user-callCreate]: Beginning execution of "europe-west4-call-user-callCreate"
function[europe-west4-call-user-callCreate]:{
                                              "verifications": {
                                                   "app": "MISSING",
                                                   "auth": "VALID"
                                              },
                                              "logging.googleapis.com/labels": {
                                                "firebase-log-type": "callable-request-verification"
                                              },
                                              "severity": "DEBUG",
                                              "message": "Callable request verification passed"
                                            }
function[europe-west4-call-user-callCreate]: Finished "europe-west4-call-user-callCreate" in 23.3241ms
```

I am guessing it has something to do with wrong setup of appcheck or initialzation of my app, but I can't find any strange things there. Maybe I need to send the app with the data to the cloudfunction in some way?

Am I doing something wrong in the calling of my cloudfunction or is the problem deeper in my system?